# Image resizing in SSRS

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, image-resizing

I have a report in SSRS which has multiple images in different sections of the report. These images may not be of the same height and width. I am trying to fit these images proportionally in image control on the report so when the image is wider than the page it fits it in the image box but looses some quality which is OK with me. The image control is a square on the report to fit it proportionally so when the image is not the same height of the control there is white space between the end of image and preceeding text. **Is there any way I can get rid of this white space?**
The text box in SSRS expands and shrinks based on the text in it, **can an image control do the same in SSRS?**

Answer (score 1):

Put an image in a **table** that has only one cell.

Create a dataset with the query `SELECT 1`. This will give you a dataset of one row.

Create a table connected to the above dataset. Remove the extra columns and rows - you just need one static column.

Add an image to the table.

Change **Sizing** to **AutoSize**.

Change **Value** to the formula to decide which image to use.

The table will grow to accommodate larger images and push whatever is around it to account for the size.

Since you have images which may be larger than the page width, you probably want to size the table all the way across and use **FitProportional**.

Comment: Hi Hannover, I already do this but when i do Fit-proportional i have to specify the height of the image control. my question was can SSRS dynamically change the height of Image control so i don't get empty white space.

Comment: I am trying to get the image fit the page widht wise if its that wide and dynamically change the height.

Comment: Ah - yes. You're right. The **FitProportional** would make it stay the same height and width as the table. I think the closest you can get is to use **AutoSize**. It will grow to fit the pics actual size but not stretch it across the page. Or use **FitToSize** which would render all pics at one size. Personally I hate stretching images - they rarely look right.

Comment: I guess I am gonna have to see HTML to PDF now

Comment: How many images do you have? Maybe resize them manually in Paint if there aren't too many and they don't change.